# Beta privado, até quando?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, beta

## Editado: Esqueça esta pergunta. Agora já estamos no beta público. :)

O Stack Overflow em português, ainda está em beta privado, após 13 dias.

Entretanto, não entendo porque ainda não podemos ir para o beta público.

A [comunidade de ebooks](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46400/ebooks) por exemplo existe há apenas 7 dias, mas já está em beta público. A [comunidade de aviação](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42572/aviation) que existe há apenas 8 dias também.

Nossos indicadores na [área 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese) são ótimos:

- No momento temos 15.5 questões por dia em média. Os limites são: Menos de 5 é ruim; de 5 a 15 é mais ou menos; e mais que 15 é saudável.
- 91% das nossas perguntas estão respondidas. Os limites são: Menos de 80% é ruim; de 80% a 90% é mais ou menos; e mais que 90% é saudável.
- Temos 783 usuários no total, sendo que destes 45 são usuários ávidos (tem mais de 200 pontos de reputação). 1 usuário, (o talles) já ultrapassou 2000 pontos de reputação. O recomendável é pelo menos 150 usuários com 200 ou mais de reputação, 10 usuários com 2000 ou mais de reputação e 5 com 3000 ou mais.
- Temos em média 2.3 respostas por pergunta. Os limites são: Menos de 1 é ruim; de 1 a 2.5 é mais ou menos; e mais que 2.5 é saudável.
- Temos em média 434 visitas por dia. Os limites são: Menos de 500 é ruim; de 500 a 1500 é mais ou menos; e mais de 1500 é saudável. Com o tempo cerca de 90% das visitas são de robôs de busca como o google.

O indicador do número de usuários ainda não está bom neste momento, mas isso ocorre exatamente porque ainda somos muito jovens e o nosso site ainda não é aberto, e mesmo assim estamos crescendo rapidamente de forma que em pouco tempo teremos estes números em um nível satisfatório para um site adulto, mesmo se continuarmos no beta privado.

O único indicador aonde estamos aparentemente mal é no de média de visitas por dia. Mas isso é algo superficial, e ocorre exatamente porque ainda estamos em beta privado e só quem já está no clubinho entra. Além disso deste total praticamente nada são vindos de robôs de busca, que não são capazes de fazer o login para acessar as perguntas e respostas do site. Portanto podemos concluir que neste quesito o nosso site também é super saudável.

Com estes números podemos concluir que em 13 dias de beta **privado**, fechado apenas para o clubinho, longe dos olhos do google e com o feriado do natal neste período, estamos muito-bem-obrigado em 2 dos 5 indicadores, quase nisso em um terceiro e os outros dois estão assim simplesmente porque somos novos demais e ainda não estamos abertos ao público.

Deixando de lado os números e olhando para o conteúdo, vemos que a qualidade das perguntas está excelente, a qualidade das respostas está excelente e a qualidade dos comentários estão bons. Além disso, a comunidade está se auto-regulamentando, se auto-moderando e se auto-organizando sozinha muita bem. Mesmo ainda em beta privado, já há comunidades de desenvolvimento que eram mantidas em fóruns migrando para cá (ex: Laravel 4), convidando os usuários em massa. Isso é sinal de que a fase crítica de inicar o site com conteúdo de qualidade e definir quais são os primeiros passos já passou.

Então a pergunta: **Porquê ainda não estamos no beta público?**

Alguns podem argumentar que é por causa de alguns bugs a resolver. A menos que exista um bug muuuuuito grave, acho que não deveria ser motivo. Basta se lembrar que os brasileiros invadiram facilmente o orkut em 2004, que na época estava todo em inglês e era infestado de todo tipo de bug monstruoso e de "no donuts for you", mas mesmo assim o povo entrou em massa sem saber inglês e se divertiu bastante [uma pena que o google foi negligente e omisso com ele e o facebook soube se aproveitar disso]. Ou seja, "não interessa se tem bug, vamos usar mesmo assim".

Comment: +1 pela pergunta, quase um -1 por ter citado o Orkut :D

Comment: Creio que as "férias" estejam atrapalhando. Logo que acabar estas "festas" acho que iremos avançar em algo.

Comment: Não dá para comparar este site com outros da Area51. No fundo somos cobaias de um experimento para ver se vale a pena ter SO em outras línguas, e acho que a SE quer ir com calma (além do que, o Gabe já disse que as traduções precisam estar finalizadas para o beta público, e ainda falta traduzir/revisar um monte de coisa). Infelizmente acho que isso quer dizer que o prazo para o beta público é "de 6 a 8 semanas"...

Comment: @bfavaretto Acho que é isso mesmo, primeiro traduzir e "afinar" como vai ser o comportamento do site. Só depois "é se deve abrir as portas"... Caso contrário é como abrir uma loja ao público sem preços dos artigos _(Já imaginaram a confusão?)_

Comment: Quanto aos índices de sustentabilidade, não deveríamos nos preocupar, porque 3 deles ficarão ótimos alguns dias depois de ir a público, um deles é bem baixo no original e só um me preocupa, mas isso pode melhorar. É a média de respostas por perguntas. Está baixo porque muitas perguntas artificiais estão sendo colocadas. Mesmo essa talvez não seja um grande problema porque está sendo incentivado que tenha isso no site. Infelizmente muitas das perguntas artificiais são muito básicas, que estão em guias de introdução, e o pior, são votadas em exagero. Isso me preocupa mais.

Comment: Enquanto estamos no beta privado, sugiro a todos sair convidando outras pessoas. Não há mal algum em fazer isso, pelo contrário.

Comment: Já convidei quase dez pessoas do grupo abntex2 (pacote de formatação ABNT para o LaTeX), mas não os vejo muito ativos aqui no site...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Sim, temos um beta MUITO bem sucedido

Conforme dito, nosso site vai muito bem em todas as métricas que nós consideramos e, além da atividade no site principal, temos também um Meta bastante movimentado

#### Esse não é um beta privado "normal"

O esforço necessário para construir esse site foi bem maior que o normal, desde o começo. Além do trabalho de localização, havia também a necessidade de alguém para gerenciar a comunidade em língua portuguesa, entre outras coisas. Da mesma forma, nós sabíamos que os desafios seriam maiores aqui, justamente pelas diferenças entre esse e os outros sites da rede. Tivemos que lidar com problemas de tradução da interface, com alguns já conhecidos (a Central de Ajuda) e outros em lugares que vocês estão nos ajudando a encontrar. Além disso, precisamos pensar a respeito das situações que podem ocorrer quando se tem um site de conteúdo similar a um outro site da rede, mas que está em outra língua. Por conta disso, nós estamos indo com calma, e tentando resolver o máximo possível antes de abrir a porteira.

Podem ter certeza que nós também mal podemos esperar pra abrir o site, então esse é o plano:

#### O site vai com certeza para o "beta público"

Pronto, é isso. Mas não é hora de relaxar. É hora de continuar o ótimo trabalho até agora, aumentando e melhorando o conteúdo e mantendo o site o mais ativo possível. Quando o site se tornar público, nós queremos que ele tenha uma grande chance de atrair novos visitantes, que façam do site a sua casa e ajudem a fortalecer a comunidade.

O tempo maior de beta privado não era para testar o desempenho, era apenas reflexo de um maior número de preparativos que nós tínhamos que realizar.

#### Queremos passar para o beta público antes do fim de janeiro

O plano ainda pode mudar se acontecer alguma coisa muito inesperada, mas nós acreditamos que tudo vai dar certo e nós vamos poder remover a barreira de acesso ao site. É bastante provável, também, que a URL do site passe para `pt.stackoverflow.com`, como vocês sugeriram.

#### Então, continuem o bom trabalho, e façam perguntas

Quando um site novo tem um grande número de *experts* (como é o caso do SOPT), o principal risco é a estagnação da atividade no site por conta da falta de novas perguntas. Isso não quer dizer que vocês tem que começar a fazer um monte de perguntas ruins, mas caso você se lembre de algum problema que enfrentou no passado, não pense duas vezes e faça uma pergunta sobre ele. Veja se alguém consegue arranjar uma solução melhor do que a sua, e se ninguém der uma sugestão melhor, responda sua própria pergunta. Da mesma forma, se você vir alguma pergunta muito interessante no Stack Overflow em inglês que você gostaria de tornar disponível em português, pode traduzir e quem sabe nossa comunidade não chega a uma resposta ainda melhor?

Comment: Ah, mas isso eu já sabia :)

Comment: O plano de finalizar a tradução antes do beta público está mantido?

Comment: @bfavaretto O site vai ao ar sem estar 100% traduzido. Por isso o status de "beta" vai ser mantido, só que dessa vez num sentido *Google* de beta, não no sentido *Stack Exchange* de beta.

Comment: @Gabe Entendi, então a tradução vai estar pronta em 6 a 8 semanas. :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Talvez mais tarde :D

Answer (score 3):

Segundo o **FAQ**

**Q:** Quanto tempo o beta privado vai durar?

**A:** Normalmente eles duram entre 1 e duas semanas, mas o caso do Stack Overflow em Português é bem diferente do resto, então esse período de beta pode durar mais.

Comment: Que FAQ? Você pode incluir um link?

Comment: @bfavaretto o FAQ estava junto ao convite do beta privado (enviado por e-mail) para nós.